# How to pass same id to elastic search api

Tags: python, elasticsearch

- I have a list of dictionary which is below
- I need to pass same id into the elastic search index as from the input
- My code is below I have passed `id=e['id']` to the code still elasticsearch is generating new id?

`r = [ { "id": "1", "name": "Mak"}, { "id": "2", "name": "Mar"}, { "id": "3", "name": "Fat"}, { "id": "4109", "name": "Ays"} ]`

Code is below

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='data', ignore=400)
  for e in r:
        es.index(index="data", body=e, id=e['id'])
```

Comment: code seems to be working perfectly.    "hits":[{"_index":"data","_type":"_doc","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":{"id":"1","name":"Mak"}},{"_index":"data","_type":"_doc","_id":"2","_score":1.0,"_source":{"id":"2","name":"Mar"}},{"_index":"data","_type":"_doc","_id":"3","_score":1.0,"_source":{"id":"3","name":"Fat"}},{"_index":"data","_type":"_doc","_id":"4109","_score":1.0,"_source":{"id":"4109","name":"Ays"}}]

Comment: I used elasticsearch7.8 module

Comment: Whats the version of `Elasticsearch` and whats the version of `elasticsearch pip library` you are using @aysh ?